# Qt manejo de archivos QFile

Tags: c++, qt, archivo

Estoy empezando en QtCreator y estoy intentando el manejo de archivos. Quiero guardar un `int` en un archivo, y que al presionar un botón me muestre ese numero en un `QSpinBox` pero no sé cómo retornar el carácter tipo `int`.

Mi código de prueba:

- `m` seria el valor del archivo quiero algo como `m=qdebug`, pero no sé cómo lo puedo hacer.

```cpp
  ui->setupUi(this);
  tiempo=new QTimer(this);
  connect(tiempo, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(archivo()));
  QString text1;
  int n, m;
  QFile file("file.txt");
  file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate);
  QTextStream text(&file);
  text1="hola";
  n=5;
  text<<n;
  file.close();
  QFile filea("file.txt");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QTextStream texto(&filea);
  QDebug<<texto.readAll();
  //m=Qdebug; o algo que me permita mostrar el contenido como int
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  ui->spinBox->setValue(m);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suele ser problemático reutilizar variables más allá de su responsabilidad inmediata. ¿No ves nada raro aquí?

```
QFile filea("file.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream texto(&filea);
QDebug<<texto.readAll();
```

Venga, una pista:

```
QFile filea("file.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); // <<--- AQUI
QTextStream texto(&filea);
QDebug<<texto.readAll();
```

Declaras la variable `filea` con la intención de leer el dato que has guardado anteriormente pero... después te pones a configurar `file`, el objeto utilizado para guardar el valor en el fichero...

Para evitar este tipo de problemas lo ideal es tener funciones lo más pequeñas posibles y, si esto no es posible, reducir el ámbito de las variables al máximo:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
tiempo=new QTimer(this);
connect(tiempo, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(archivo()));
QString text1;

{
  int n;
  QFile file("file.txt");
  file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate);
  QTextStream text(&file);
  text1="hola";
  n=5;
  text<<n;
  file.close();
}

{
  QFile filea("file.txt");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); // ahora aqui tenemos error de compilación
  QTextStream texto(&filea);
  QDebug<<texto.readAll();
}
```

Aparte de eso, si lo primero que contiene el fichero es el entero a leer, el algoritmo a utilizar es tan complicado como el que sigue:

```
int m;
QFile filea("file.txt");
filea.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); // <<--- AQUI
QTextStream texto(&filea);
filea >> m;
```

Ya has leido el valor... pero lo que quieres es usarlo en **otra función** diferente... tienes varias opciones pero con el poco código que enseñas yo recomendaría crear una variable miembro:

```
class MainWindow
{
  int m;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
  : m(0) // Repasa todos los constructores
{ }

// int m; ya tenemos la variable miembro, esta no es necesaria
QFile filea("file.txt");
filea.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); // <<--- AQUI
QTextStream texto(&filea);
filea >> m;
```

Con esto tu función ya debería darte el resultado esperado:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  ui->spinBox->setValue(m);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Es mas facil que todo eso, pero lo primero que deberías plantearte a la hora de usar un fichero para guardar información es como lo vas a estructurar y entonces usar los métodos apropiados.
Si vas a guardar información de valores simples como el contenido en varios spin box te recomiendo que uses el QSettings (ficheros Ini de toda la vida). Asi este es el codigo para el boton Leer y el boton Guardar :

```
#include <QSettings>

void MainWindow::on_Leer_clicked() {

    QSettings oSet("file.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
    int m=oSet.value("Dato spin").toInt();
    ui->spinBox->setValue(m);
}

void MainWindow::on_Guardar_clicked() {

    QSettings oSet("file.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
    QString m=QString::number(ui->spinBox->value());
    oSet.setValue("Dato spin",m);
}
```